# Data grid display icon on one column

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

IM using data grid which are filled with data during RT(Im using mvvm).
I bind the data grid to observer collection which is updated during RT with values.

one of the fields are isKey .if this value is true I want to display some icon of key.
how can i do that?

I need to add the icon just when **key is true** .

this is my code

model

```
  public bool IsKey { get; set; }
        public string Column2 { get; set; }
        public string Column3 { get; set; }



  {
        public ViewModel()
            {
            this.Items = new List<MyClass>();
            //row 1:
            this.Items.Add(new MyClass { IsKey= true,Column2 = "aaaa",Column3 = "ddfa",Column4 = "fddsfas",Column5 = "dfadsfas"});
            //row 2:
            this.Items.Add(new MyClass { IsKey = false ,Column2 = "aaaa",Column3 = "ddfa",Column4 = "fddsfas",Column5 = "dfadsfas"});
            }
```

the xaml

```
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding isKey}" Header="2" Width="*" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Column2}" Header="2" Width="*" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Column3}" Header="3" Width="*" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Column4}" Header="4" Width="*" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `DataGridTemplateColumn`. Set its `CellTemplate` to contain `ContentControl` whose **Content will be null in case IsKey value is false and set it to Icon when value is true for IsKey**.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn IsReadOnly="True">
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <ContentControl x:Name="content"/>
         <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsKey}" Value="True">
              <Setter TargetName="content" Property="ContentTemplate">
                 <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                       <Image Source="IconSourcePath" Height="30"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                 </Setter.Value>
              </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
         </DataTemplate.Triggers>
      </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: HI Rohit,thank,but what is the content and why I need it?this is the table which have the data ?currently i use <DataGrid RowHeaderWidth="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">

Comment: `content` is ContentControl name which is needed to show data on GUI. Like `DataGridTextColumn` internally uses `TextBlock` to host your data on GUI. Similarly i have used ContentControl to show Icon on GUI. What's your icon which needs to be shown?

Comment: Thanks,just change the icon from content to resource ...I have another question but i'll open new tread.

Comment: Ok great. It should be resource instead.